# Replace Items In Matrix Based on Value

Tags: r, matrix, replace

I have a matrix that contains integer values that represent the index of the item in an array and I'd like to switch out item 1 for the values[1] and so on for each item in the values array.

Some code to demonstrate what I'd like

```
> m = matrix(1:3, ncol=3, nrow=3)
> m
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1    1
[2,]    2    2    2
[3,]    3    3    3
> replace(m, 1="a", 2="b", 3="c")
> m
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] "a"  "a"  "a" 
[2,] "b"  "b"  "b" 
[3,] "c"  "c"  "c"
```

Basically it takes 1 and turns it into "a" and so on. It seems like if I try to do this with a for loop it changes after the first iteration from int to string and since I'd like to do this with any object type that's not great behavior.

Comment: I have not the slightest idea what is the question, but are you looking for something like `"dim<-"(letters[m], dim(m))`?

Comment: Will this be restricted to 1, 2, 3 and a, b, c, or do you need a more general solution?

Comment: I need a general solution that replaces each item that matches a value with another item. In the above case I write 1="a" to indicate that all 1 values are going to be replaced with the string "a". The left side of the equation will always be integer values but the right side could be anything, in this case it's a string but it may be from another integer to a function.

Comment: Would that work for you `Match_func <- function(x, y) "dim<-"(y[match(unique(x), seq_along(y))], dim(m));
vec <- c("Ralf", "Jhons", "Pete");
Match_func(m, vec)` ?

Comment: Could also try `revalue` from the `plyr` package, something like `library(plyr);"dim<-"(revalue(as.character(m), c("1" = "a", "2" = "b", "3" = "c")), dim(m))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of three possibilities to solve this

```
m <- matrix(1:3, 3, 3) # Your data
```

---

## **1**

Either define a function that will get a vector in the correct matching order (the first entry will match the first unique value in `m`, etc.)

```
vec <- c("Ralf", "Jhons", "Pete")
```

Then you can define a simple function such as

```
Match_func <- function(x, y) "dim<-"(y[match(unique(x), seq_along(y))], dim(x))
```

Test

```
Match_func(m, vec)
#      [,1]    [,2]    [,3]   
# [1,] "Ralf"  "Ralf"  "Ralf" 
# [2,] "Jhons" "Jhons" "Jhons"
# [3,] "Pete"  "Pete"  "Pete"
```

---

## **2**

The second option will be to define your manual replace function, something like

```
Match_func2 <- function(x, ...) {
  temp <- list(...)[[1]]
  "dim<-"(temp[match(x, as.numeric(names(temp)))], dim(x)) 
}
```

Test

```
Match_func2(m, c("1" = "a", "2" = "b", "3" = "c"))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,] "a"  "a"  "a" 
# [2,] "b"  "b"  "b" 
# [3,] "c"  "c"  "c"
```

---

## **3**

You can also make a use of `plyr::revalue`

```
library(plyr)
Match_func3 <- function(x, ...) {
  temp <- list(...)[[1]]
  "dim<-"(revalue(as.character(x), temp), dim(x))
}
```

Test

```
Match_func3(m, c("1" = "a", "2" = "b", "3" = "c"))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,] "a"  "a"  "a" 
# [2,] "b"  "b"  "b" 
# [3,] "c"  "c"  "c"
```

---

*Note:* The last approach is the safest in case you don't want to replace *all* the unique values

Answer (score 0):

Here's an option, starting with a character matrix so that you don't need to worry about making a copy or coercion of the original matrix.

```
m = matrix(as.character(1:3), ncol=3, nrow=3)
old <- as.character(1:3)
new <- c("a", "b", "c")
for (i in 1:length(old)) {
    m <- ifelse(m == old[i], new[i], m)
    }
```